# Two-Variable Data Table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, spreadjs

Can I create a "Two-Variable Data Table" (aka "Two-Way Data Table") in JavaScript?

In Excel, of course, this can be found in the Data, What-If Analysis, Data Table menu sequence.

Answer (score 2):

SpreadJS's team has implemented a dataTable function that is used to create the two-way-table:  `function dataTable(sheet, columnRange, rowRange, colInputCell, rowInputCell, formulaCell)`

Here is the entire dataTable function:

```
 function dataTable(sheet, columnRange, rowRange, colInputCell, rowInputCell, formulaCell) {
            var colRg = GC.Spread.Sheets.CalcEngine.formulaToRange(sheet, columnRange);
            var rowRg = GC.Spread.Sheets.CalcEngine.formulaToRange(sheet, rowRange);
            var colCell = GC.Spread.Sheets.CalcEngine.formulaToRange(sheet, colInputCell);
            var rowCell = GC.Spread.Sheets.CalcEngine.formulaToRange(sheet, rowInputCell);
            var fCell = GC.Spread.Sheets.CalcEngine.formulaToRange(sheet, formulaCell);

            for (var i=colRg.col; i<colRg.col + colRg.colCount; i++) {
                sheet.setValue(colCell.row, colCell.col, sheet.getValue(colRg.row, i));
                for (j=rowRg.row; j<rowRg.row + rowRg.rowCount; j++) {
                    sheet.setValue(rowCell.row, rowCell.col, sheet.getValue(j, rowRg.col));

                    var v = sheet.getValue(fCell.row, fCell.col);
                    sheet.setValue(j, i, v);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is an example of how you would create the data table using this function:

```
function createDataTable() {
    var ss = GC.Spread.Sheets.findControl('ss');
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    ss.suspendPaint();
    dataTable(sheet, 'G1:K1', 'F2:F6', 'B1', 'B2', 'B4');
    ss.resumePaint();
}
```

<sub>I am a member of GrapeCity's Technical Engagement team.</sub>

Comment: This answer is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413087).